# In WatchOS, how to prevent a List from passing tap events to a tappable view?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to set up a carousel list on WatchOS.  Each row in the list has a Toggle in it.  I want the user to have to tap the Toggle itself to interact with it; however, the list row seems to be passing any taps anywhere on it to the toggle.  This happens for Buttons as well.  How can I disable this behavior?

I wrote the following sample View to illustrate what's happening:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var value:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Toggle("test", isOn: $value)
            Button("test"){
                print("Button pressed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following output: 

[TestView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW8ML.png)

Whenever a tap is registered anywhere in the first list row, the Toggle is switched.  Whenever a tap is registered anywhere in the second list row, the button's action (printing to the console) is triggered.  I would like it such that the Toggle only registers a tap when it itself is tapped.  I tried adding `.onTapGesture{}` , which works partially, but doesn't stop long presses from getting through.  Adding `.onLongPressGesture{}` breaks scrolling, making it not a viable option either.

Any advice?